# Type ChangeListener does not take parameters

Tags: java, parameters, javafx, arguments, changelistener

I'm trying to create ChangeListeners for some properties of my stage, but I can't figure out how to...

```
mainScene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
    @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneWidth, Number newSceneWidth) {
        System.out.println("Width: " + newSceneWidth);
    }
});
```

gives the error "type ChangeListener does not take parameters".

```
    mainScene.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<>() {
        @Override public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number oldSceneWidth, Number newSceneWidth) {
            System.out.println("Width: " + newSceneWidth);
        }
    });
```

gives "cannot infer type arguments for ChangeListener". It feels like a "damned if you do, damned if you don't" situation to me. Removing the parentheses after the <> gives a boatload of errors...

EDIT: Imports:

```
import javafx.application.Application;

import javafx.stage.*;

import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.beans.*;
import javafx.beans.property.*;

import javafx.geometry.*;
```

Comment: You probably have the wrong import statement.

Comment: @James_D do you know which would be the proper one? I can edit my post to include imports.

Comment: None of those will import a `ChangeListener`, unless I am missing something. You need `import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;`. Make sure you do not have the `ChangeListener` from Swing (which doesn't have type parameters).

Comment: @James_D that worked, thanks! If you add it as an answer I can approve it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have likely imported the `ChangeListener` from the Swing API (which doesn't take type parameters) instead of the JavaFX `ChangeListener`. Make sure you have the correct import:

```
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of all that difficult-to-understand codes  as well as that import by using lambda expression:

```
mainScene.widthProperty ().addListener ( (ObservableValue <? extends Number> observableValue , Number oldSceneWidth, Number newSceneWidth) -> System.out.println("width: "+ newSceneWidth));
```

You can make it more short if you don't need the `newSceneWidth`. 
Like:

```
mainScene.widthProperty ().addListener (e -> System.out.println("SceneWidth Changed"));
```